# Scrapy finish redirect before crawling next URL

Tags: python, scrapy

Whenever Scrapy gets a 302, that action is added as the last item in the queue. Is there a way to force Scrapy to finish the redirection and process next urls after that?

Comment: Can you try to increase [`REDIRECT_PRIORITY_ADJUST`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#redirect-priority-adjust) value to see if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Tomáš in the comment `REDIRECT_PRIORITY_ADJUST` controls redirect priority.

However what you describe with default scrapy settings shouldn't happen since this setting defaults to `+2`. By default all scrapy requests are scheduled at `0`, so all redirected requests should have priority over other requests.

You can schedule indidividual requests priority with `priority` argument.
for example if you want to set priority at `100`, you'd write this:

```
yield Request("http://someurl.com", priority=100)
```